# Exibir Popup pedindo autenticação quando clicar em componente de tela que não tenha permissão para alterar

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Como criar um mecanismo para, quando o usuário clicar para tentar alterar uma data que está como `datepicker` e exibir um *popup* para autenticação ou algo do tipo para realizar essa alteração? Se ele tiver permissão, ele consegue, senão, não consegue.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function ($) {
                $.datepicker.regional['pt-BR'] = {
                    closeText: 'Fechar',
                    prevText: '&#x3c;Anterior',
                    nextText: 'Pr&oacute;ximo&#x3e;',
                    currentText: 'Hoje',
                    monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Mar&ccedil;o', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho',
                    'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
                    monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
                    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda-feira', 'Ter&ccedil;a-feira', 'Quarta-feira', 'Quinta-feira', 'Sexta-feira', 'Sabado'],
                    dayNamesShort: ['D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S'],
                    dayNamesMin: ['D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S'],
                    weekHeader: 'Sm',
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                    firstDay: 0,
                    isRTL: false,
                    showMonthAfterYear: false,
                    yearSuffix: ''
                };
                $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['pt-BR']);
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#txtNovaDtVenc").datepicker(
                    { changeMonth: true, changeYear: true }).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
            });
        </script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Detalhes", "Faturas", FormMethod.Post, new { target = "_blank" }))
            { 
                <div class="div-detalhes">
                    <label> 
                        @Html.Hidden("NumeroDoc", Model.NumeroDocumento)
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NumeroDocumento) : 
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NumeroDocumento)
                    </label>
                    <label> 
                        Sacado : 
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.sacado.Nome)
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ValorBoleto) : 
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ValorBoleto)
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataVencimento) : 
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DataVencimento)
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataDocumento) : 
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DataDocumento)
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Nova dt. de vencimento : 
                        @Html.TextBox("txtNovaDtVenc", "", new { @class = "form-control form-control-custom", style="width:100px" })
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input class="btn btn-padrao-bv" type="submit" id="btnImprimir" value="Imprimir"/> |
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                   </label>
                </div>

            }
```

Comment: Você já possui alguma forma de autenticação em sua aplicação?

Comment: @Randrade Cara, possuia, mas o pessoal pediu pra tirar e agora pediu pra colocar só pra quem for alterar essa data que no caso é uma data de vencimento de um boleto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uma possível solução que eu vejo seria, você trazer da sua ViewModel um booleano, e aí você poderia verificar na view se o usuário está ou não logado e se possui permissão com um simples IF....

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txtNovaDtVenc").datepicker(
                { changeMonth: true, changeYear: true
}).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        });
    </script>
```

primeiramente sugiro que você ao invés de usar o ID use a Classe nos Input...

```
$(".DatePicker").datepicker(
```

porque aí você não precisa repetir o código novamnete em outros campos, se puder colocar em uma PartialView melhor ainda !!! assim você pode usar o código em todas as suas Views que possuírem datas que precisam ser alteradas.

daí você poderia criar um:

```
@Html.Hidden("IsLogado", Model.IsLogado)
@Html.Hidden("PodeAlterar", Model.PodeAlterar)
```

e aí você pega pegar esses valores com o .val() do jquery.

```
var IsLogado = $( "#IsLogado" ).val();
var PodeAlterar = $( "#PodeAlterar" ).val();
```

você poderia criar uma function para verificar se pode alterar a data:
com if statement verificando:

```
function PodeAlterarData {

if (!IsLogado) {

     return //código
  // para chamar a pop-up que irá pedir o login do usuário
  //         não se esqueça de setar os valores do input
  //com o usuario logado caso ele faça o log in
   }

if(!PodeAlterar) {

   return
  //exibir uma mensagem de erro dizendo que ele não possui 
  // privilégios de alteração

   }
return true;
}
```

obs: não se esqueça de dar returns caso os if sejam satisfeitos pois aí ele encerra a function.

e por fim: você poderia fazer um simples:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".DatePicker").datepicker(
            { changeMonth: true, changeYear: true
}).attr('readonly', 'readonly');

        $(".DatePicker").click(function() { 
         if(!PodAlterar)  { 
         // bloqueia o campo
        }            
});

        $(".DatePicker").dblclick(function() {
          if(!PodAlterar)  { 
         // bloqueia o campo
});
    });
</script>
```

sugiro que coloque um timeout de verificação entre um click e outro para garantir que não bugue !

Comment: Desculpa cara, agora que vi. Então, eu tinha essa autenticação ao entrar no site, mas me pediram pra tirar pq ai foi pedido que todo mundo poderia ver, beleza, eu fiz, ai agora pediram pra eu colocar uma autenticação só nesse datepicker. É possível ?

Comment: sim claro que é possível, te mandei uma das formas de se fazer, talvez não a melhor, mas funciona :)

Comment: eu pensei numa situação mais fácil, mas estou com um probleminha. Vou abrir outra pergunta, vê se vc consegue me ajudar por favor ?

Comment: se quiser continuar pelo chat, tudo bem, mas abre sim outra pergunta, as pode ser que muitos tenham a mesma dúvida.